# Fetch big tree without overhead in left tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, tree

My question is more theoretical and it is about why do RDBMS/drivers return data the way they all do it, not how they find a correct set, nor how to find it. I'm pretty familiar with SQL, but there is one thing that always annoyed my sense of economy.

Consider following "class" graph:

```
A {
    field1, ..., field9
    b_items = [ b1, ..., bN ]
}

B {
    field1, ..., field6
    c_items = [ c1, ..., cM ]
}    

C {
    field1, field2
}
```

We have few A objects, each A object has many B objects, and each B objects has lots of C objects. `count(A) < count(B) << count(C)`.

Now I would like to use a RDBMS to store it, because relations are cool and optimizers are smart, so I can get virtually anything in milliseconds, provided there is a good plan and index set.

I'll skip table creation code, which should be obvious, and go straight to the select:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.b_id = B.id
WHERE whatever
```

Database server returns the result set combined of all columns from all tables, properly joined into the sort-of tree:

```
A.f1 .... A.f9  B.f1 .... B.f6  C.f1 C.f2
---------------------------------------------------
   1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1
   1    1    1     1    1    1     2    2
   1    1    1     1    1    1     3    3
   ... more rows...
   1    1    1     1    1    1   999  999
                        ↓
   1    1    1     2    2    2     1    1
   1    1    1     2    2    2     2    2
   ... more rows...
   1    1    1     2    2    2   999  999
   ... lots of rows ...
   1    1    1    99   99   99   999  999
        ↓
   2    2    2 -- oh there it is, A[2]
   ...
   5    5    5  NULL NULL NULL  NULL NULL -- A[5] has no b_items
   ...
   9    9    9 ...
```

The problem is, if A has many columns, especially with text, json, other heavy data, it is duplicated thousands of times to match each product of +B+C join. Why don't SQL servers at least simply **not** send me **the same** {A,B}-rows after the first one in join group? Ideally, I would like to see something like that as a result:

```
[
  {
    <A-fields>,
    B = [
      {
        <B-fields>,
        C = [
          {
            <C-fields>
          },
          ... more C rows
        ]
      },
      ... more B rows
    ]
  },
  ... more A rows
]
```

which pretty much resembles what I actually need to get in memory on the client-side. I know I can make more queries to fetch less data, e.g. via `A.id IN (ids...)` or stored proc returning nulls on parasite rows, but isn't relational model intended for one-shot access? Roundtrips are heavy, and so are planner guesses. And real data graphs are rarely of only 3 steps height (consider 5-10). Then why not make it all via single pass, but without excessive traffic?

I'm fine with duplicate cells in A and B columns, because usually there is not too much, but maybe I'm missing something mainstream, **SQL** and **non-hacky** that google hides from me for so many years.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at recursive CTE's https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html

Comment: That is how SQL is defined to work.  Tables have a full complement of columns for each row.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid duplicated data transfer is to use aggregate functions like `string_agg ()` or `array_agg ()`. You can also aggregate the data using jsonb functions. You can even get a single json object instead of tabular data, example:

```
select jsonb_agg(taba)
from (
    select to_jsonb(taba) || jsonb_build_object('tabb', jsonb_agg(tabb)) taba
    from taba
    left join (
        select to_jsonb(tabb) || jsonb_build_object('tabc', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(tabc))) tabb
        from tabb
        join tabc on tabc.bid = tabb.id
        group by tabb.id
        ) tabb 
    on (tabb->>'aid')::int = taba.id
    group by taba.id
) taba
```

[Complete working example.](http://rextester.com/LIRU19469)

Comment: Hmmmm, but why I never looked into json aggregation before? Thanks for your efforts, I must give it a try on my data!

Answer (score 1):

json_agg() may not be the fastest thing.Also, I wonder if your ORM will digest it properly and instantiate the right objects.

The usual way is to simply do:

```
SELECT ... FROM a WHERE ...
```

Then you recover the ids, and do:

```
SELECT ... FROM b WHERE a_id IN (the list you just got)
SELECT ... FROM c WHERE a_id IN (the list you just got)
```

These are utually autogenerated by an ORM. If the ORM is smart, you get one query per table. If it is dumb you get one query per object... However, this forces three queries, with network roundrips, plus some processing. Fortunately, postgres will let you have your cake and eat it, although that takes a little bit of extra work.

Thus, you can create a function in plpgsql which returns "SETOF refcursor". Since a refcursor is a cursor, a function can return several result sets.

[Example](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure).

Back in the day when I was doing sql for websites, I used that a few times. Mostly when you just want to fetch one object and a few dependencies, so the actual query parsing and planning takes longer than the queries themselves which return one line or a few. There it uses a function, so everything is already compiled. It's very efficient.